# scrapy stops crawling with 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, scrapy

I am crawling a web with scrapy and I receive the error:

```
Gave up retrying <GET https://www.something.net> (failed 3 times): 500 Internal Server Error
```

even though in the parse method I have added this parameter to the meta of the `scrapy.Request` that calls the parse function:

```
"handle_httpstatus_all": True,
```

Then in the parse function I do:

```
item = response.meta['item']
if response.status == 200:
    #Keeps building the item
yield item
```

So in theory this should not happen. What can I do to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theory is missing some vital information.

Scrapy has two different sets of middleware that each request must pass through.  The one you are referring to is the [`HttpErrorMiddleware`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#module-scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror) which is belongs to the `Spider-Middleware` group.   If this middleware is enabled and you set the request meta key `handle_httpstatus_all` to `True` then it does in fact allow all failed requests through to be parsed.

However there is another group of Middleware called the `Downloader-Middleware` which are passed through first before the requests/responses ever reach the `Spider-Middleware`.  Among these is the [`RetryMiddleware`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry) which identifies responses with certain error codes that are determined to be potentially temporary and automatically resends those requests up to a certain number of times before the response is officially considered failed.

So your theory is still accurate in the sense that all failed responses are allowed to go through, but for some error codes they first go through a few retry attempts before they get processed.

You can customize the middleware's behavior by setting the number of retries with `max_retry_times` meta key to a custom value,  or setting the `dont_retry` meta key to `True`, or you can disable the retry middleware altogether in your settings with `RETRY_ENABLED = False` .

You can also customize which error codes are considered eligible for retry with the [`RETRY_HTTP_CODES`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#retry-http-codes) setting.